# Real URL only shows me index.php?id=xx when changing language

Tags: hyperlink, localization, typo3, realurl

If I look at my default language the links have speaking url (www.yoursite.com/company/about-us.html). But now I added a language and if I look at the links I get

`www.yoursite.com/index.php?id=63&L=1`

What is wrong? This is my Typoscript for the list menu:

```
lib.tsfootermenu1 = COA
lib.tsfootermenu1 {

  10 = HTML
  10.value = <p class="ContentOverviewHeading">


  15 < tmp.tsfootermenu1

  20 = HTML
  20.value = </p>

  25 = HMENU
  25  {
    special = directory
    special.value = 63
    entryLevel = 0

    1 = TMENU
    1.wrap = <ul>|</ul>
    1{
        expAll = 0
        NO{
          ATagTitle.field = title
          wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
          ATagParams = class="SubMenu1"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

The TS reads out all elements in a folder and shows a list. I have added a page translation for the folder and the elements in it, but I still get the index.php?id=xx URL. Of course I cleared the real url and page cache.

Edit:

My realURL config:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl'] = array ( 
'_DEFAULT' => array (
    'init' => array (
        'enableCHashCache' => '1',
        'appendMissingSlash' => 'ifNotFile',
        'enableUrlDecodeCache' => '1',
        'enableUrlEncodeCache' => '1',
    ),
    'redirects' => array (
    ),
    'preVars' => array (
        '0' => array (
            'GETvar' => 'no_cache',
            'valueMap' => array (
                'nc' => '1',
            ),
            'noMatch' => 'bypass'
        ),
        '1' => array (
            'GETvar' => 'L',
            'valueMap' => array (
                'de' => '0',
                'en' => '2',
                'valueDefault' => 'de',
            ),
            'noMatch' => 'bypass',
        ),
        '2' => array (
            'GETvar' => 'lang',
            'valueMap' => array (
                'de' => 'de',
                'en' => 'en',
            ),
            'noMatch' => 'bypass',
        ),
    ),
    'pagePath' => array (
        'type' => 'user',
        'userFunc' => 'EXT:realurl/class.tx_realurl_advanced.php:&tx_realurl_advanced->main',
        'spaceCharacter' => '-',
        'languageGetVar' => 'L',
        'expireDays' => '7',
        'rootpage_id' => '1',
    )
```

**Edit:**
My solution looked like I changed the complete config to L=2. Typo3 has obviously some problems with a deleted language.

Comment: have you checked your realURL config? the additional language needs to be configured there as well. if you use automatic configuration you may want to delete the file typo3conf/realurl_conf.php.

Comment: realURL is working for other submenus. In addition for the default language it works. I have edited my question to show you my realURL config. The folder with the pages is outside of the `rootpage_id`. But is this the reason? As I said, for the default language it is working ...

Answer (score 0):

At least you did not define an mapping for L=1, only L=0 or L=2 in your Realurl config.

Comment: I had a problem with L=1 and so I created another language with L=2. So this isn't the reason. I only gave L=1 as example in my question.