# TYPO3: how to recover a deleted language?

Tags: typo3, recovery, recover, realurl

In the table `pages_language_overlay` I can see that there are entrys with sys_language_uid = 1. But there is no language if i look under list on page with id=0. How can I recover the language?

The problem is that I tried to create a new language with the id = 1 on a copy of the project. Then I had some problems because TYPO3 didn't get it managed it right with realURL ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212016/real-url-only-shows-me-index-phpid-xx-when-changing-language)). What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create an additional language record for your website:

- in backend: activate the list module
- select the root node of the whole page tree (id=0)
- check if there is already a block "Website Language" with a record in it
- if not: click on "Create new record" (little icon with green plus close to top of window)
- select System Records -> Website Language
- select the name, ISO code and flag for your language
- save

Now make sure that your new language record has id=1. If the ID is higher your autoincrement value in table sys_language was not zero (possibly because you have created and deleted a language earlier). In this case you will have to modify sys_language manually (export to SQL, modify SQL accordingly, delete table and reimport).

Cheers, Jörg.

Comment: If I don't need the translations, can I empty the table `pages_languages_overlay`? The table `sys_language` is empty in my case. But I have to create the language first to see the autoincrement value.

Comment: What I don't understand: Despite there is no second language, if I call `http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?L=1` I get some results (from the table pages_languages_overlay). I thought I would first need a language for that?

Comment: Yes indeed, sys_language is needed to manage any records in additional language in the backend, but not to display pages in the frontend.
And Yes, you can empty pages_languages_overlay if you don't need the other language data any more. If you really want to clean up, you should also delete all content elements from tt_content that have sys_language_uid==1. They won't hurt but they are garbage.